# CMake: Multiple executables for different platforms sharing common code

Tags: c, cmake, raspberry-pi-pico

I'm a CMake-beginner. Here's a problem I cannot figure out.
I have a project structure that looks like this:

```
root
| common/
|   include/
|      public.h
|   src/
|      file-1.c
|      file-2.c
| win-exec/
|    main.c
| pico-exec/
|    main.c
```

`win-exec` is a Windows executable binary that depends on code in `common/`. It also depends on GLFW and a few other Windows-specific libraries.

`pico-exec` is another executable binary for the Raspberry Pi Pico that depends on code in `common/`. This also has dependencies on the Pico SDK.

So basically I want different executables for different platforms.

How would you structure this as a CMake-project? The executables both need to compile the common code, since the executables need to be built for different architectures.

Is it possible to define different targets (with seperate toolchains) that somehow also recompiles the common code in the process? Or should I approach this outside of CMake with a batch-file for instance?

Comment: Have seperate `CMakeLists.txt` files for the two binaries. Alternatively can have a single CMakeLists.txt with platform conditionals.

Comment: @kaylum is right -- those are your two options. I'd recommend the separate projects route.

Comment: Add the common code to a static lib. Add a `CMakeLists.txt` file to `common` and be sure that this file does not generate any files to the source tree. This allows you to add the common logic to the separate projects without duplicating the common logic. If desired you could add a toplevel `CMakeLists.txt` file that adds the subdirectory depending on the target platform; something like: `add_subdirectory(common) if (WIN32) add_subdirectory(win-exec) else() add_subdirectory(pico-exe) endif()`

Comment: Thanks you all for your suggestions! I have a couple of things to try now, thank you!

Comment: @fabian Is this even possible without a top-level CMakeLists? How does the binary projects know about the library project? add_subdirectory doesn't seem to like parent directories.

Comment: @r1sc you CAN use any directories with `add_subdirectory`, but if the specified directory is not a subdirectory to the current source directory on the file system, you need to specify a second parameter dedicating a binary directory for the directory to use.